# "No repositories available" in Visual Studio 2017 when connecting to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

When I try to connect to TFS 2015 from within Visual Studio 2017, I get the message "No repositories available". The tfs server is listed, but I cannot connect.
No problems in Visual Studio 2015.
Do you have an idea, what I could do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a new UI design changed by Visual Studio 2017.

> In Visual Studio 2017, we changed the behavior of the Connect page. We
> now populate the Connect Page list with only the items you’ve
> selected.
>
> **If you select a project and click "Connect", you will see only the project node in the Connect page. To get your repositories to appear
> on the Connect page you need to select the repository node in the
> Connect dialog and hit Connect.**
>
> This change was made in response to feedback from folks who had large
> numbers of repositories in their team projects and wanted to not have
> them all added whenever they connected to anything in said project.

More details please  refer the *visual studio team's* comment in this similar question: [Team Explorer does not show the repositories within a multi repository project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26340/team-explorer-does-not-show-the-repositories-withi.html)

Comment: I cannot connect to a project, because no project will be listed. The connect button is disabled.

Comment: @MarcoWittwer Have you followed this tutorial for VS2017, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer There should be a list after you select a TFS server.

Comment: @MarcoWittwer Another way is trying to remove your TFS2015   entries from your credential store(Control Panel -> Manage Windows Credentials ) Connect to the server in VS2017 again.

Comment: remove entries from credential store does not fix the problem.

See this screenshot: https://ibb.co/dh9tcF Perhaps it helps while finding the error.

Comment: I found this error in the Event Viewer of TFS:
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 18.08.2017 05:19:51

Detailed Message: TF246024: An error occurred while attempting to build catalog nodes. A catalog node is missing the following path to its parent: 3eYRYkJOok6GHrKam0AcAA==hEjbR2iMPUS8BNnyBdyscg==iuIFvJBEkU+IAt0V27NeaQ==.

Web Request Details
    Url: http://cark25w.---:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/CatalogService.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 15.112.26421.0, Other, SKU:59)

Comment: @MarcoWittwer will take a look and have a test in myside, what's detail version of your VS2017? Any update will post here asap.

Comment: @MarcoWittwer According to your screenshot and error info in event viewer, seems there are not even establishes connection between TFS2015 and VS2017. The issue is either related to TFS or VS2017 side. If you could also connect to the same TFS sever in VS2015 without any extra setting, then highly doubt it's related to VS2017. Did you have any other VS2017 with the same version in another machine, suggest you give a test on another machine, this will narrow down the issue.

Comment: @MarcoWittwer Another way  is trying to 1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. Delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`.  3. restart VS to sign in and try the connection again

Comment: We have version 15.2 (26430.16) of Visual Studio Professional 2017. We have the problem in all our installations (3 notebooks).

I think the config database of TFS is corrupt. When I search the"missing parent"  entries in table tbl_CatalogNode and tbl_CatalogResource I can see, that this are very old projects. This comes from an other collection. And this collection we do not need anymore.
Can we rebuild the configuration database? How?

Comment: Did you do any TFS server upgrade or migrated recently? Did you have any back up of the collection you are connecting? You could simply restore database to the last known good state from back up. Detail ways please refer this tutorial--[Restore data to the same location](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs)

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Gotta say it's super, super annoying that you can't just tell the TFS GUI to delete a collection and then have it delete it NO QUESTIONS ASKED. What I mean is, if it's corrupted, then you're screwed. I wasn't thinking today and accidentally tried to remove a db in SQL before TFS finished detaching. Total brain fart on my part, but the frustration that stuff like that causes is way more than it should be. TFS ought to be smart enough to delete the collection out now w/o me needing to do manual sql operations in management studio. Just ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue ,for me TFS is using Kerberos authentication. I changed the authentication to NTLM by running command from Developer tools under TFS server.

TFSConfig Authentication [/provider:NTLM|Negotiate] [/viewAll] [/siteType:ApplicationTier|Proxy]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops#authentication

We also did IISRESET after this.

After this i am able to view the Repos under visual studio.